# Video downloader app implemented in RxJs

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have used multiple map/flatmap combinations. Could anybody help me with the review?

```js
var Rx = require('rx');
var RxNode = require('rx-node');
var request = require('request');
var _ = require('lodash');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

exports.getResult = function(req, res) {
    var result = '';
    fetchContent({
            url: req.body.url
        }, req.body.season)
        .flatMap(getEpisodeRange)
        .map(formEpisodeUrl.bind(null, req.body.url, req.body.season))
        .flatMap(downloadHtml)
        .map(getGorillaUrl)
        .flatMap(postToGorilla)
        .map(getVideoUrl)
        .flatMap(prepareHtml)
        .subscribe(function(data) {
            result += data;
        }, function(error) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(error))
        }, function() {
            res.send(result);
        });
}


function fetchContent(params) {
    console.log(params.url);
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
        request(params, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                observer.onError();
            } else {
                observer.onNext({
                    response: response,
                    body: body,
                    args: args
                });
            }
            observer.onCompleted();
        })
    });
};

function prepareHtml(url) {
    return `<a href=${url}></a>`;
}

function fileName(url, season, episode) {
    return Rx.Observable.just(url.split('/'))
        .last().map(function(name) {
            return name.replace('_', ' ').concat(` S${season}E${episode}`);
        });
}

function getVideoUrl(data) {
    var pattern = /"http(.*)(\.flv|\.mkv|\.mp4)"/;
    var matches = pattern.exec(data.body);
    if (matches && matches[0]) {
        return matches[0]
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function postToGorilla(url) {
    var params = {
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        form: {
            op: 'download1',
            method_free: 'Free+Download',
            id: _.last(url.split('/')),
        }
    }
    return fetchContent(params)
}

function getGorillaUrl(data) {
    try {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data.body);
        var url = $('a[title="gorillavid.in"]').first().attr('href').split('=')[1]
        return url = new Buffer(url, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    } catch (error) {
        return Rx.Observable.just(null);
    }
}

function downloadHtml(url) {
    return fetchContent({
        url
    });
}

function formEpisodeUrl(url, season, episode) {
    return url.replace('/serie/', '/episode/').concat(`_s${season}_e${episode}.html`);
}

function getEpisodeRange(data) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data.body);
    return _.range(1, ($('span').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === `Season ${data.args[0]}`;
    }).parents('h2').siblings('ul').children('li').length) + 1 || 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall, I think this is very decent code, some observations:

**JSHint**

- Use JsHint ;)
- You have a number of missing semicolons, and an unnecessary semicolon
- `return url = new Buffer(url, 'base64').toString('ascii');` <- I dont think you wanted to assign to `buffer`?
- You are not using the function `fileName(url, season, episode){` anywhere

**Odd stuff**

- You use the extremely cool `fetchContent({ url });` but also the mundane

  ```
  {
    response: response,
    body: body,
    args: args
  }
  ```

  You should stick to 1 approach
- Your regex `/"http(.*)(\.flv|\.mkv|\.mp4)"/`

  - Is not supporting avi, wmv, or mpg file extensions.
  - Is not supporting uppercase incoming file names extentions.
  - Keeps repeating the `\.` for each extension, so I would keep that out of the brackets.
  - If you plan for many entries, then I would keep the regex outside of the function, and generate that regex only 1 single time for performance
- You have a stray `console.log(params.url);`, get rid of it
- It seemed odd that the HTML you prepare has no text in the anchor:

  ```
  return `<a href=${url}></a>`;
  ```

  Also, do you want to consider at least surrounding the URL with double quotes?

**Sugar**

- You use `req.body` 3 times in `getResult`, I would have had a `var params = req.body;` as a shortcut
- This seems a good use case for a ternary:

  ```
  if (matches && matches[0]) {
      return 
  } else {
      return null;
  }
  ```

  could be

  ```
  return (matches && matches[0]) ? matches[0] : null;
  ```

  I am still not sure why you return `null` actually. PrepareHtml will return `<a href=null></a>`, so perhaps consider

  ```
  return (matches && matches[0]) ? matches[0] : '';
  ```

**Anonymous functions kill kittens every day**

- The 3 functions within your `subscribe` call are anonymous. It is in general terrible to look at a stack trace filled with anonymous functions
- You also have one in `getEpisodeRange`
- I do like that you declare your other functions 'the right way'

**Comments go a long way**

- `getEpisodeRange` needs comments, it is the most intense code
- There are actually no comments at all in this code, and I can parse everything just fine except the above mentioned function

**Style**

- Formatting looks good to me
- Naming looks good to me
- I did not find obvious repetitions from a DRY perspective

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  It is really helpful.. But Can you please review this from the reactive perspective as well. Because this is my first reactive program. I am not sure if this is the right way.

Comment: I need a name for the a link as well. That is why I created the `fileName` function. I can only call the `fileName` function from my `getEpisodeRange` function but i couldn't find a way to pass that to the `generateHtml` function in the map chain.

Comment: @Sreevisakh I think your usage is awesome, almost tutorial worthy. I will check the fileName thing and see if I can find a work-around.